# Unable to GET multiple Isset variables

Tags: php

I am trying to show specific data if two variables are set in a form.

```
$retired = "";
$stolen = "";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $retired = $_GET['showretired'];
    $stolen = $_GET['showstolen'];
}
```

I have tried the bellow:

`<?php }elseif(isset($_GET['showretired']) && (isset($_GET['showstolen'])){ ?>`

Which does not work

`<?php }elseif(isset($retired, $stolen)){`

Which works when not set

`<?php }elseif(isset($_GET['showretired'], $_GET['showstolen'])) {`

This one only shows the retired part.

I am unsure of the best way to do this.

Here is the form:

```
    <form>
        <label>Show Retired Column </label><input type="checkbox" name="showretired"> 
        <label class="space">Show Stolen Column </label><input type="checkbox" name="showstolen">
        <input class="space" type="submit" name="submit" value="Refine">
    </form>
```

This is how I am using the variable in the same file.

```
              <?php }elseif(isset($_GET['showretired'], $_GET['showstolen'])) {
                    ?>
                <tr>

                    <th>Retired</th>
                    <th>Stolen</th>
                </tr>
                <?php }else{ ?>
```

Comment: Why are you checking for a POST within your if statement and then checking for get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(isset($_POST['showretired'])) {
        $retired = $_POST['showretired'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['showstolen'])) {
        $stolen = $_POST['showstolen'];
    }

    if(isset($retired)){
    echo $retired;
}
if(isset($stolen)) {
    echo $stolen;
}
}



?>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <label>Show Retired Column </label><input type="checkbox" name="showretired" value="The retired field"> 
    <label class="space">Show Stolen Column </label><input type="checkbox" name="showstolen" value="The showstolen field">
    <input class="space" type="submit" name="submit" value="Refine">
</form>
```

Comment: I still only get retired displayed#

Comment: That has to do with your checkboxes. The need a `value="checked"`

Comment: So I gave them values and still no change

Comment: Ok so it "works".  But it shows them without me running the form

Comment: Now I understand the issue, Sorry I had my error reporting turned off. I updated code. Should work fine now.

Comment: Afraid not, heres the file http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jryVNB?editors=1000

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115528/discussion-between-frank-w-and-saucedapples).

Answer (score 0):

No method on the form means it will default to GET.  Change the conditional and check your checkboxes.

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
    $foo = isset($_GET['foo']) ? true : false;
    $bar = isset($_GET['bar']) ? true : false;
    var_dump($foo);
    var_dump($bar);
}

?>

<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo">
    <input type="checkbox" name="bar">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Ok so doing this does not change the result but adds undefined indexs for `showretired` and `showstolen`

Comment: @SaucedApples they would be undefined if the checkboxes were not checked.  Have updated answer to include a checkbox check.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_GET['submit'])){

        if(isset($_GET['showretired']) &&  $_GET['showretired'] !="" && isset($_GET['showstolen']) && $_GET['showstolen'] !="" )
        {

            echo $retired."   ".$stolen;
        }


    }
```

and form

```
<form>
    <label>Show Retired Column </label><input type="checkbox" name="showretired" value="showretired" checked="checked"> 
    <label class="space">Show Stolen Column </label><input type="checkbox" name="showstolen" value="showstolen" checked="checked">
    <input class="space" type="submit" name="submit" value="Refine">
</form>
```

Hope it will help